# Time Difference separating the times

Tags: java, time

> ```
> Complete timeDifference that takes two different times and returns a 
> string with the difference in hours and minutes, separated by ":". 
> The int argument 0 represents midnight, 700 is 7:00 a.m., 1314 is 14 
> minutes past 1:00pm, and 2200 is 10 pm.  
> Leading zeros required
> ```

I know the problem requires you to convert both times to minutes, however I don't know how to separate the integers that are four characters long so I can differ between hours and minutes.

Comment: `String#subString` would be good start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sice your question is on the separation part only, this will do the trick:

```
int timeDifference(int a, int b)
{
    int minsA = a % 100); //remainder
    int hrsA = (a / 100);
    .....
}
```

Edit: if you want to get the full time just in minutes you can do:

```
int fullMinsA = minsA + hrsA*60;
```

Comment: what is gonna happen to variable b that you pass to your function?

Comment: so i have the correct formula, all i need to do is figure out how to get the leading 0s for both columns

Comment: @KickButtowski - you're gonna do the same thing for b, and then do your calculations based on defined hrs and minutes (or only minutes).

Comment: @moo the return Value will be a String. you can force leading zeroes into Strings. So try to think like this. if hours or minutes < 10 then you need to add a leading zero to your String part.